# When are functions included in the global scope?

Tags: php

When I submit my php files to a server, are functions included in the global scope as soon as the file containing them is requested or this files are compiled as soon as I upload them? Do these functions remain in memory or they are parsed on every request?

Answer (score 0):

They are parsed on every request.

PHP is not compiled in machine code but interpreted on runtime and executed.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense. PHP is not some persistent process that you can introduce new files/functions to. When you upload a file to your server, that file doesn't *do* anything until you actually run it. If you're using a web server that supports PHP, you would probably run the PHP file by making an HTTP request.

PHP is a program that parses and evaluates the contents of a script. That script can include other scripts. In *that specific instance* of PHP, the functions are global (if they're declared as such) as soon as the function's declaration has been parsed and executed.